# Cannot restart RPC server (windows sdk)

Tags: c++, rpc, winapi

I use the following commands to stop the RPC server

```
RPC_STATUS status;
while(RpcMgmtWaitServerListen() != RPC_S_NOT_LISTENING)
    status = RpcMgmtStopServerListening(NULL);
RPC_BINDING_VECTOR *binding_vector;
status = RpcServerInqBindings(&binding_vector);
if (status)
{
    throw std::exception("RPC ERROR!");
}
status = RpcEpUnregister(Comms_v1_0_s_ifspec,binding_vector,NULL);
if (status)
{
    throw std::exception("RPC ERROR!");
}
status = RpcBindingVectorFree(&binding_vector);
if (status)
{
    throw std::exception("RPC ERROR!");
}
```

When i invoke the `RpcEpUnregister` statement it ends with a **cannot perform operation on endpoint error**.

if i use the following code to stop the server

```
RPC_STATUS status;
while(RpcMgmtWaitServerListen() != RPC_S_NOT_LISTENING)
    status = RpcMgmtStopServerListening(NULL);
status = RpcServerUnregisterIf(NULL,NULL,FALSE);
```

upon server restart `RpcServerUseProtseqEp` throws endpoint **The endpoint is a duplicate**
no matter how much i try running the code `RpcServerUseProtseqEp` its still the same.

Comment: With a 0.01% margin of error: nobody writes code like this on Windows.  Use COM.

Comment: im sorry im trying to achieve two things.  1. Learn multithreaded rpc 2. Make the code above simple. The communication is happening between two remote pc's